# highcharts typeerror this is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I have a highcharts function that populates a chart. It also has a drilldown event that needs to be called when the drilldown event is triggered.

I get this following error when I drilldown the charts-

```
TypeError: this.filter_data is not a function
```

The drilldown event is in the populate_group_by_gender_chart function under the options/chart/events.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Container,  } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import Wrapper from './Components/Wrapper';
import _ from 'lodash';
import './App.css';

let county_data =  'https://data.m.gov/api/views/kdqy-4wzv/rows.json?accessType=DOWNLOAD'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      raw_data: [],
      employee_data: [],
      column_names: [],
      page_num: 1,
      group_by_gender_data: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {          
      fetch(county_data).
        then(response => response.json()).
        then(response => {          
          // console.log(response.data)          
          let column_names = _.map(response.meta.view.columns, 'name')

          const data_map = response.data.map(data=> {
            return {
                id: data[0],
                'full_name':data[8],
                'gender':data[9],
                'current_annual_salary':data[10],
                '2018_gross_pay_received':data[11],
                '2018_overtime_pay':data[12],
                'department':data[13],
                'department_name':data[14],
                'division':data[15],
                'assignment_category':data[16],
                'employee_position_title':data[17],
                'position_under_filled':data[18],
                'date_first_hired':data[19]                
            }
          })
          // console.log('data_map - ', data_map)
          let grouped_data_by_chunks = _.chunk(data_map, data_map.length/100)

          // console.log('grouped_data -', grouped_data_by_chunks)

          this.setState({
            raw_data: data_map,
            employee_data: grouped_data_by_chunks[0],
            column_names: column_names
          })                                  
          this.populate_group_by_gender_chart(data_map);
        })
  }

  populate_group_by_gender_chart = (data) => {
    console.log('drilldown this.filter_data -', this.filter_data)

    var options = {
      chart: {
        type: "pie",        
        events:{
          drilldown: function(e){
            console.log('e.point.name - ', e.point.name)            
            var filter_by = (e.point.name = 'Female') ? 'F': 'M'            
            this.filter_data('GENDER', data, filter_by)            
          }
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Employees by Gender'
      },
      series: [          
        {
          name: 'Gender',
          data: []
        }
      ],      
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {}
        },        
        },    
      };
      options.series[0].data = this.filter_data('GENDER', data)
      this.setState({
        group_by_gender_options: options
      })
    }

  filter_data = (filter, data, filter_by) => {      
    if (filter == 'GENDER'){
      data = _.map(data, 'gender')        
      data = _.filter(data, function(val){
        return val == 'F';
      })
      const result = _.values(_.groupBy(data)).map(d => ({'y' : d.length,
                                                        'name' : d[0] == 'F' ? 'Female': 'Male',
                                                        'id': d[0] == 'F' ? 'F': 'M',
                                                        'drilldown': true
                                                      }));

      return result
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Container fluid={true}>

          <Header/>

          <Wrapper data={this.state.employee_data}
                   group_by_gender_chart_data={this.state.group_by_gender_options}
          ></Wrapper>

        </Container>      
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue with a sample data on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: I got this fixed, the 'this' in the chart event is referring to the chart and not the component.